# Hazelcast hangs when server fails to handle query

Tags: hazelcast

I want to execute instance of supertype AbstractEntryProcessor (lets say SomeEntryProcessor) with IMap.executeOnKey method.
Server side ClassLoader doesn't have this class (SomeEntryProcessor).
So it expectedly fails with:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.package.SomeEntryProcessor
com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.HazelcastSerializationException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.package.SomeEntryProcessor
    at com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.DefaultSerializers$ObjectSerializer.read(DefaultSerializers.java:190) ~[hazelcast-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
    at com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.StreamSerializerAdapter.read(StreamSerializerAdapter.java:40) ~[hazelcast-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
    at com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.SerializationServiceImpl.readObject(SerializationServiceImpl.java:279) ~[hazelcast-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
    at com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.ByteArrayObjectDataInput.readObject(ByteArrayObjectDataInput.java:433) ~[hazelcast-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
    at com.hazelcast.map.client.MapExecuteOnKeyRequest.read(MapExecuteOnKeyRequest.java:88) ~[hazelcast-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
```

But after this executeOnKey hangs forever. 
I believe this happens due to infinite wait in method

```
ClientCallFuture.get(long timeout, TimeUnit unit) {
  ...
  this.wait(waitMillis); // line 103 in hazelcast 3.2.3
}
```

Has anyone seen the same?
Created an issue https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/issues/3842, but no response received

Answer (score 0):

Sorry somehow missed the issue. Can you try a 3.3.x release? I guess the issue is fixed on those versions.